# How to fix Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am testing a URL in flutter, but keep getting an error:

> Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.
> final loginUri = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL, Config.loginAPI);
> ^

```
class Config {
  static const String appName = "appName";
  static const String apiURL = http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
  static const String loginAPI = "api/dj-rest-auth/login/";
}
 
class AuthService {
  final loginUri = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL, Config.loginAPI);
```

The error is showing for `Config.loginAPI`
How do I fix this error knowing that they are both strings, not int related to them.

What is the reason for it and how to fix it?

Comment: `Uri.parse(Config.apiURL + Config.loginAPI)`

Comment: You need quotes around the contents of `static const String apiURL` in your class `Config`.

Answer (score 3):

static const String apiURL = http://127.0.0.1:8000/;

This code is wrong.

Follow correct code.

static const String apiURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
class Config {
  static const String appName = "appName";
  static const String apiURL = http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
  static const String loginAPI = "api/dj-rest-auth/login/";
}
 
class AuthService {
  final loginUri = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL, Config.loginAPI);
```

to

```
class Config {
  static const String appName = "appName";
  static const String apiURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";
  static const String loginAPI = "api/dj-rest-auth/login/";
}
 
class AuthService {
  final loginUri = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL, Config.loginAPI);
```